# Backslashes in Windows makefiles

Tags: windows, makefile, mingw

Important edit: I've since solved the problem with my specific makefile, but I don't know how.

I replaced backslashes with forward slashes and it turns out my rules work fine with those.  Gcc accepts mixed forward and back slashes, so it worked fine.  A sticking point existed with `mkdir`: it doesn't accept paths with mixed forward and back slashes.  I changed my variables to include only back slashes in the Windows version, and now the file works perfectly.

For reference, here's some new rules and variables:

`OUT = $(ROOT)\out
SRC = $(ROOT)\src
$(OUT):
    mkdir $(OUT)
$(OUT)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<`

Why does minGW-make accept mixed slashes in rules after variable expansion but not backslashes-only?  What exactly is going here?

---

### Original post

I have a minGW install of make for windows.  I copied my unix makefile and converted the commands to windows (and forward slashes to backslashes) but the resulting makefile does not work.

The main difference is that Windows has `$(OUT) = $(ROOT)\out\win` and Unix has `$(OUT) = $(ROOT)/out`.  Unix works fine.  `make -f makefile.win` on windows complains that there is no rule for `<root>\out\win\LinkedList.o`.  The rules and error in question are:

`` make: *** No rule to make target `H:\CodeRIT\1014Syllables\out\win\LinkedList.o', needed by `H:\CodeRIT\1014Syllables\out\win\bin\syllables.exe'.  Stop. ``

`$(OUT)\%.o:  $(ROOT)\src\%.c
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<`

`$(OUT)\bin\syllables.exe: $(OUT)\LinkedList.o $(OUT)\Syllable.o $(OUT)\Model.o
        gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^`

$(OUT) should expand to `<root>\out\win` giving the file it complains about a clear target.  I don't understand why this rule doesn't work, given that the same rule works just fine on Unix.  Is there some arcane rule about maximum directories in targets or something?  I don't have enough experience with make to really assess what's going wrong here.

Here's the full text of the file in question: https://github.com/blastedt/syllables/blob/master/makefile.win

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(OUT)\%.o:` does not define a pattern rule, you've [escaped](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Usage) the `%`.

`$(OUT)\\%.o:` should work in this case, although it's because of gotchas like this that it's best to avoid backslashes when using make on Windows.

You will run into issues with shell commands like `mkdir` and `del` not working with forward slashes, you should consider switching to powershell, cygwin, MSYS2, or [bash on windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about).

Comment: Thanks! I've seen a lot of documentation suggesting things like `PATH_SEP = \\` or a function that replaces / with \ before execution.  Are those reliable solutions to fix these issues?

I use bash on ubuntu on windows but in my experience it isn't able to execute files I make so I needed the Windows build chain as well.

Comment: @Blastedt I experimented myself with a few different things like replacing slashes, or writing cmd scripts to replace bash features like `rm`, in the end it was too much of a hassle and I switched to powershell + forward slashes, it's been installed by default since Windows 7 anyway.

Comment: We've had an issue with GNU make on Windows (version 3.81), where make did not recognize that a dependency of one target was the same as a target if the target and the dependency weren't 100% lexically identical. So make would complain "No rule to make target blah blah blah" or something to that effect. We went to great lengths to make sure all paths are specified using backslashes only. :-\