# How to change drive in Makefile?

Tags: bash, cmd, makefile, gnu-make

The target (rule) in my Makefile has a series of commands. First few commands should be executed from D:\ drive. After this, I should change my directory to C:\ so that I can execute a file in C:\ drive. But, I am not able to change drive. I tried the following ways:

- C: (it works in cmd but not in Makefile)
- cd /d C: (not working)
- cd C: (not working)

Please let me know how to change drive from within a make rule.

Comment: As suggested in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455549/backslashes-in-windows-makefiles you could try using slashes instead of  backslashes in the directory name

Comment: The drive letter is not a path, the root path of a drive is referred to by a single slash, (backward in Windows, forward in nix flavors). You're therefore looking for the drive letter followed by its root drive. `CD /D C:\` will change the current directory to the root of the `C:` drive. `CD /D D:\` will change the current directory to the root of the `D:` drive. The `/D` option allows for moving between drives, and not just locations within the same drive. If you're unsure of your current directory, it is always safer to include that option.

Comment: Please also note that you do not have to change your current directory or drive in order to execute a command. You could also use `PushD` as an alternative, `PushD C:\ ` or `PushD D:\ `, but should remember to use `PopD` with each, to return to the previous location afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using either ; or && \

```
cd d:\folder1 && \
dir && \
echo "all files in d:\folder1 are listed"

cd c:\folder2 && \
dir && \
echo "all files in c:\folder2 are listed"
```

is equivalent to

```
cd d:\folder1; dir; echo "all files in d:\folder1 are listed"

cd c:\folder2; dir; echo "all files in c:\folder2 are listed"
```

Comment: `cd` does not change current drive unless `/d` is given, which is `cmd`-specific. For sake of portability, I would use `pushd` that happens to work with `cmd`, PowerShell and Linux-based shells.